# How to make mouseEntered work correctly in an Applet program.

Tags: java, swing, paint, mouselistener, japplet

I'm new to Java applets and I have to make a program where the pupils of two eyes follow a cursor.

There is a box around the face and when I enter the box with the cursor the "eyes" are supposed to center. I can't get the MouseListener mouseEntered to work right and fire when I drag the cursor over a component.

Thanks for any help you can give.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class LookingProgram extends JApplet {

// 
private int currentX = 0; 
private int currentY = 0; 

//Pupil sizes:

//PUPIL ONE 
private int pupilOneX = 350;
private int pupilOneYheightY = 350; 

//PUPIL TWO 
private int pupilTwoX = 500; 
private int pupilTwoY = 350; 

//Left 
private int leftRightP1 = pupilOneX - 15;
private int widthRightP2 = pupilTwoX - 15;

//Up
private int heightUpP1 = pupilOneYheightY - 30;
private int heightUpP2 = pupilTwoY - 30;

//Down 
private int heightDownP1 = pupilOneYheightY + 30;
private int heightDownP2 = pupilTwoY + 30; 

//Right 
private int LookRightP1 = pupilOneX + 10;
private int LookRightP2 = pupilTwoX + 10;


private int widthDownP1Y = pupilOneYheightY + 30; 



private boolean isEntered; 
private boolean exited; 

/**
 * Init method
 */

public void init()
{
    // Sets the background color to white. 
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

    //Motion listener
    addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());

    //Mouse Listener
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
}

 /**
 * paint method
 */

public void paint(Graphics g)

{
    // Call the super class paint method

    super.paint(g); 

    //Black bordered rectangle

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(200, 200, 500, 500);


    g.fillOval(pupilOneX, pupilOneYheightY, 65, 50);
    g.fillOval(pupilTwoX, pupilTwoY, 65, 50);
    g.fillOval(450, 450, 25, 25);

    g.drawOval(330, 295, 100, 150);
    g.drawOval(480, 295, 100, 150);
    g.drawLine(550, 550, 350, 550);



}

private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e )

    {

            pupilOneX = 350;
            pupilOneYheightY = 350; 


            pupilTwoX = 500; 
            pupilTwoY = 350; 
            repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {



    }
}

private class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener
{


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {


    }


    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 

    {

        currentX = e.getX(); 
        currentY = e.getY(); 


        // Look left
        if(currentX < 350)
        {
            pupilOneX = leftRightP1; 
            pupilTwoX = widthRightP2; 

        }

        //Look Right
        if(currentX > 450)
        {
            pupilOneX = LookRightP1; 
            pupilTwoX = LookRightP2;


        }


        //Look Up
        if(currentY < 150)
        {
            pupilOneYheightY = heightUpP1;
            pupilTwoY = heightUpP2;

        }

        // Look down
        if(currentY > 500)
        {
            pupilOneYheightY = widthDownP1Y; 
            pupilTwoY = heightDownP2;

        }
        repaint(); 

    }
}

}
```

Comment: You might want to mark this as homework. Most people here aren't keen on just handing out homework answers.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  @AdamP the [tag:homework] tag was retired dome time ago.